# Using ReplaceAll to simplify derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

I'm struggling trying to simplify the derivative of a function. I know that `ReplaceAll` works like that:

[image]

What I want is to replace the function itself that should appear inside its derivative expression, but it did not work as you can see below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there any way of doing that in Mathematica?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please present a minimal example as Mathematica code so that potential respondents can copy it to their notebooks and experiment with it. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! A couple things: (1) `ReplaceAll` works by pattern matching, not by numerical equality, and machine-precision numbers (like `1.`) do not match exact numbers (like `1`). (2) you seem to be trying to replace this expression with `ahs`, but I think you'd likely want to replace it with `ahs[rho, T]`; `ahs` is the function itself while `ahs[rho, T]` is the value. (3) since `ReplaceAll` works by pattern matching, it won't work unless that big expression appears more-or-less verbatim in the result. So what you might want is `Eliminate` to algebraically get rid of the `zeta`s!

Comment: Hey @thorimur. Thank you so much for your comments. I finally found what I looked for in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179703/simplify-symbolic-equation-substituting-parts-with-other-expressions?rq=1. Thanks!